# CGRectIntersectsRect frame + -10

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a question.

I want that two objects collide. Here's my current code:

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(_redBall.frame, _boxRed.frame)) {


    score = score + 10;
    _redBall.center = CGPointMake(240, 160);

    _scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %i", score];


}
```

I want that those two objects (_redBall and _boxRed) collide, but that they collide at (for example) frame -10 or another value. Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "frame -10"?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Check `CGRectOffset`

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006894-CH3-SW30)

```
CGRect original = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
UIEdgeInsets adjustment = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-5, 10, 20, -30); // top, left, bottom, right
CGRect adjustedRect = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(original, adjustment);

// adjustedRect = {10, -5, 130, 80}
```

This will then allow you to adjust all the edges, and therefore the position of the `CGRect`.

As someone mentioned there is also [`CGRectOffset`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000955-CH1g-F17162), but that will only move the rectangle. If you want to expand it, you can use `UIEdgeInsets`.

There's also [`CGRectInset`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000955-CH1g-F17155) which is like `UIEdgeInsets`, but only grows or expands the edges on the same axis together, not individually.

I only mention all three methods as you've been a bit vague with `frame - 10`. All of the above should help you though!